# Performing a sum subquery using linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, subquery

Please could someone assist with the below query. I'm trying to select the Sum of all receipts per Client. But the 'Total =' sub query in my select section is not working and I'm getting the following error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'AppName.Domain.Entities.AccountingEntry'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I've already tried doing a ToList() after that query but this results in the same problem. What is the standard way of selecting a Sum as a subquery using linq?

```
var receipts = (from ae in repo.AccountingEntries
                        join c in repo.Clients on ae.ClientId equals c.ClientId
                        join m in repo.Memberships on c.MembershipId equals m.MembershipId

                        where
                             (ae.EntryDate <= start) &&
                             (ae.ClientId != null) &&
                             (ae.AccountingEntryTypeId == (byte)Shared.AccountingEntryTypes.Receipt)


                        select new AppName.Reports.Clients.AgeAnalysis.Receipt
                        {
                            ClientId = (Guid)ae.ClientId,
                            Client = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                            Membership = c.Membership.Name,
                            Total = (from ae2 in repo.AccountingEntries where ae2.ClientId == ae.ClientId select ae2.Total).Sum()
                        });
```

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: What type is `Total`?

Comment: Query works without calculating totals?

Comment: Total is a decimal, and yes, the query runs fine without that Total subquery part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems overly complex and unnecessary. If your entity model is set up properly, you can simplify by removing the joins and using a "group by" clause.  Something along the lines of:

```
from ae in c.AccountingEntries    
where
    (ae.EntryDate <= start) &&
    (ae.ClientId != null ) &&
    (ae.AccountingEntryTypeId == (byte)Shared.AccountEntyrTypes.Receipt)
group by
    ae.Client into g
select 
    new AppName.Reports.Clients.AgeAnalysis.Receipt
    {
        ClientId = (Guid)g.Key.ClientId,
        Client = g.Key.FirstName + " " + g.Key.LastName,
        Membership = g.Key.Membership.Name,
        Total = g.Sum( p => p.Total )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Moho, this is working perfectly. I'm quite new to EF, I didn't even realise I could group by an Entity itself which solves my whole problem.